# Google firebase test lab, compatibility testing

Tags: testing, firebase, android-webview, compatibility, firebase-test-lab

In Google firebase test lab, for custom login of my android application, I am not able to access/get the resource IDs of username and password field. This is happening because my sign in page is web-view. Is there any way to access the resource ids in web-view or any other approach to perform compatibility testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about a Robo automated test and not instrumentation tests.  Firebase Test Lab does not support WebView at this time.  It's noted in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/robo-ux-test#known_limitations).

If this is a feature you'd like to see, you can effectively vote for it by filing a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 1):

Works in 2020. In the test settings, specify the id of the html element and enter the value (password, email, etc.)

Comment: Looks more like a comment rather than an answer